# my csv file only gets one row

Tags: php

I'm outputting a temporary table to a csv file, but it only gets one row ?

here is the code

```
$fileName = fopen('cmv_sailings.csv', 'w');

while ($i = mysql_fetch_assoc($export)) {
    $ship = $i['code'];
    $title = $i['title'];
    $sailDate = $i['sailDate'];
    $fromPort = $i['fromport'];
    $nights = $i['nights'];
    $grade = $i['type'];
    $fare = $i['fare'];
    $offer = $i['offerFare'];
    $deposit = $i['deposit'];

    $content = $ship.','.$title.','.$sailDate.','.$fromPort.','.$nights.','.$grade.','.$fare.','.$offer.','.$deposit.'\n';

    fwrite($fileName, $content);
}

fclose($filename);
```

I haven't got a clue now. I was trying to use fputcsv but I can't get that working either

Comment: What's the SQL query? What's the table contents?

Comment: how many rows do you get from sql select?

Comment: Also, the use of the `mysql_` extension is discouraged. It doesn't support prepared statements.

Comment: the table contents are text fields... could it be some character in there ?

Comment: if I output the $content to the screen, it's fine...

Comment: Is there any chance that only one row from the table gets selected? Say, the table only _has_ one row.

Comment: write echo $content; after $content = $ship.....  is it showing more that one row, as your code looks ok to me

Comment: to the screen, each row comes out like this P301,Christmas Markets,12 16 2012,London, Tilbury,3 n,De Luxe Suite,1549,1329,120\n

Comment: Try to change the "$content ="  to "$content.=" and then write to file after the while loop

Comment: @Rich wait, do you really store literal `\n`, not a newline, to the CSV file?

Comment: right, now when I open it in Numbers, it says Import Warning - Tables with more than 255 columns and 65,533 rows aren’t supported. Columns 256 and higher and rows 65,534 and higher were removed.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure I think it's the newline part that's wrong... my csv is 131kb so it has all the rows but the above message is removing them all

Comment: @Rich Asaph is correct - you are creating one huge line because you're not actually appending any newline character.

Comment: @JanDvorak yea I see I've got one big line, how do I return a new line

Comment: @Rich asaph is telling you - use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`

Comment: yep I see it in the answers, doh... Perfect it works now, many thanks everyone :)

Comment: I tried your code locally pls change your code as per my ans and it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this, The main problem I can seen in your code is using single quote for \n that's why new line character is not getting added in your csv file and you are getting your result in one single line

```
$content = $ship.','.$title.','.$sailDate.','.$fromPort.','.$nights.','.$grade.','.$fare.','.$offer.','.$deposit."\n";
fwrite($fileName, $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, at the end of your `$content` variable assignment, change `'\n'` to `"\n"`. In php, escape sequences are not interpolated when using single quotes. They are interpolated when using double quotes. You're getting a literal backslash, followed by a literal `n` instead of the line break you're looking for.

As for using [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), that may not have worked for you due to using the incorrect line breaks for your platform. This happens on the Mac. If this was your issue, try turning on [`auto_detect_line_endings`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) before your file parsing code. You can do it at runtime using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) like this:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = $ship. ... .'\n';
```

You are appending a backslash and n to the file, not the newline character. Try this:

```
$content = $ship. ... ."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using mysql_ not a good idea, for now ok, but in future, migrate to PDO or mysqli
2. Preparing the CSV manually, not a good idea, special characters must be escaped, use [fputcsv description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)
3. Why you have only one row in your CSV, i think is because of some formatting problems (or missing formatting), coming from your way of formatting.